# What assembly reference do I add to use System.Win32?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use objects within System.Win32.SystemEvents, but I can't find the assembly to add to my C# project. There is no obvious dll anywhere...

Answer (score 5):

Don't you mean:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents
```

You don't need to reference any additional assemblies for that.

Assembly:  System (in System.dll). This assembly is already referenced.

Comment: @tuseau Not really - useful to have these things around for others that have the same issue and search on Google.